# How to store a custom key in AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-kms

I'm using open ssl to generate an asymmetric key locally in my machine. I want to store this key in AWS KMS. Is there a possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Importing key material in AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) - AWS Key Management Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys.html):

> Imported key material is supported only for symmetric CMKs in AWS KMS key stores. It is not supported on asymmetric CMKs or CMKs in custom key stores.

So, it seems that you *cannot* import an asymmetric key into AWS KMS.